# preg_replace и utf-8 помогите с регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, utf-8

Есть код

> $ret='[https://конкурсшкол.рф/contest-progress-project-after-grant/index](https://%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB.%D1%80%D1%84/contest-progress-project-after-grant/index)';
>
> $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n
>   ])([\w]+?://[a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9_#№$%&~/.-;:=,?@[]+]*)#is", "\1\2",
>   $ret);

$ret получается
[https://конк](https://%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA)��рсшкол.рф/contest-progress-project-after-grant/index

вычитал что модификатор /u поможет, пробовал его вставлять в строке в разные места - результат ноль.

Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался #is надо заменить на #uis